# Ошибка: при cookie-аутентификации, в конфигурационном файле необходимо задать парольную фразу

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Помогите найти ошибку в коде это файл config.inc.php

```
<?php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';  // Вот это не пропустите.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';        // Имя пользователя MySQL.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';  // Здесь надо вписать ваш пароль к MySQL.
?>
```

работаю на локальном хосте

Неверный индекс сервера:

> При cookie-аутентификации, в конфигурационном файле необходимо задать парольную фразу установив значение директивы $cfg['blowfish_secret'].

Comment: @aaabbbccc, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Это конфиг PhpMyAdmin кажется. И почему ты решил что здесь есть ошибка? Какой текст ошибки?

Comment: @aaabbbccc, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Comment: Этот вопрос напрямую связан вот с **[этим][1]**


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/329649/mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ba17c1ec07d65003'; // Не хватает этой строчки
$i=0; $i++;                                   // А еще вот этой
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
?>
```

Comment: Если добавить только этот код который вы написали,выходит В доступе отказоно
 phpMyAdmin не смог установить соединение с сервером MySQL. Проверьте хост, имя пользователя и пароль установленные в конфигурационном файле config.inc.php и удостоверьтесь, что они соответствуют данным полученным от администратора сервера MySQL.

Comment: @aaabbbccc, так сделайте то, что говорится в тексте ошибке. Проверьте имя пользователя и пароль. Точно правильно набрали?  
В вашем предыдущем вопросе я вам давал стандартные комбинации имени пользователя и пароля.

Comment: Все как вы отправили,добавил  в файл config.inc.php

Comment: @aaabbbccc, в прошлом вопросе вы так и не ответили на вопрос: какая у вас операционная система?  
База данных у вас одна? MySQL висит на стандартном порту? Пробовали авторизоваться через консоль в MySQL с этими же данными?  

Возможно, если вы испытываете такие трудности с установкой и настройкой MySQL и phpMyAdmin будет проще использовать готовые сборки, вроде http://open-server.ru/ ?

Comment: А у вас есть база данных?